# CSS cursor pointer is overriding inline style cursor on item list dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the [Nestable JS](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable) library and I got a list of nestable items in my tree, I would like to add a `cursor: pointer` when I hover on them and also, `cursor: move` when dragging. But I can't make it work.

I found that in jQuery UI happens the same thing, so here I got a little fiddle to show that:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sortableList").sortable({
        revert: true,
        cursor: 'move',
        start: function(event) {
         event.target.style.cursor = 'move';
        },
        stop: function(event) {
         event.target.style.cursor = 'default';
        }
    });
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
});
```

```css
div {
    border:1px solid red;
}

ul .ui-state-default li:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
  //cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>Draggable source items
    <ul>
        <li class="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>Sortable List 1
    <ul class="sortableList">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, if you check on the CSS part, I have the last rule commented out, because it doesn't work if the cursor is pointer for :hover on those list items. Happens the same thing as in Nestable JS.

Is there a way to avoid that overriding? To have both cursors pointer and move depending on the situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the `classes` option? *Specify additional classes to add to the widget's elements. Any of classes specified in the Theming section can be used as keys to override their value. To learn more about this option, check out the learn article about the classes option.*

Comment: Yea, i know what you say but the problem is i don't use jquery UI for my tree, im using Nestable JS, happened that in jQuery UI occurs the same thing... don't know why, is there a way to make this work via Javascript or CSS?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. I've never used Nestable JS and your tags do not include it. What classes are used when you're dragging or hovering?

Comment: Yes i know, im working on making another example using nestable. But is very basic.. the library itself doesn't have any CSS for styling draggables and stuff... so I add a cursor: pointer on every list item... and then when dragstart i try to change the style to cursor: drag and dragstop to cursor: pointer. But doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of setting the cursor style on the `:hover` itself set it to the the normal class selector.

```
.ul .ui-state-default li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This should set the cursor to pointer when the mouse pointer is moving over the element. If it isn't working like this, check if the framework which you are using has a bigger cascading level (e.g. `.first-class .second-class .thirdclass {...}`. You have to get a bigger "cascading level" like this statement in order to override it.

Or simply use `!important` (Don't use this to often, because overriding this style gets harder every time)